# Transaction: exited with an error (status 0) after consuming all gas

Tags: solidity, truffle

Hi i am creating a wallet with which i can transfer ETH on approval from 3 authorised address. My second test condition fails. I am fairly new to solidity please help.

wallet.js

```
const Wallet = artifacts.require('Wallet');

contract('Wallet',(accounts) => {
    let wallet;
    beforeEach(async () =>{
        wallet = await Wallet.new([accounts[0],accounts[1],accounts[2]],2);
        await web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:accounts[0], to:wallet.address, value: 1000});
});

    it('should heve correct approvers and quorum',async()=> {
        const approvers = await wallet.getApprovers();
        const quorum = await wallet.quorum();
        assert(approvers.length === 3);
        assert(approvers[0]===accounts[0]);
        assert(approvers[1]===accounts[1]);
        assert(approvers[2]===accounts[2]);
        assert(quorum.toNumber() === 2);

});
    it('should create transfers',async () => {
      await wallet.createTransfer(100, accounts[5], {from: accounts[0]});
      const transfers = await wallet.getTransfers();
      assert(transfers.length === 1);
      assert(transfers[0].id === '0'); 
      assert(transfers[0].amount ==='100');
      assert(transfers[0].to === accounts[5]);
      assert(transfers[0].approval === '0');
      assert(transfers[0].sent === false);
});
});
```

wallet.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Wallet{
    //address array stores address of the approvers.
    //quorum is the number of approvers.
    address[] public approvers;
    uint public quorum;
    struct Transfer{
        uint id;
        uint amount;
        address payable to;
        uint approval;
        bool sent;
    }
    Transfer[] public transfers;
   // mapping(uint => Transfer) public transfers;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint => bool)) public approvals;
    
    
    constructor(address[] memory _approvers, uint _quorum)public{
        approvers = _approvers;
        quorum = _quorum;
    }

    function getApprovers() external view returns(address[] memory){
        return approvers;
    }
    function getTransfers() external view returns(Transfer[] memory){
        return transfers;
    }
    function createTransfer(uint amount, address payable to) external onlyApprovers(){
        transfers.push(Transfer(
           transfers.length,
            amount,
            to,
            0,
            false
        ));
    }
    function approveTransfer(uint id)external onlyApprovers(){
        require(transfers[id].sent == false,'transfer has already been sent');
        require(approvals[msg.sender][id]== false,'cannot approve transfer twice');

        approvals[msg.sender][id]=true;
        transfers[id].approval++;

        if(transfers[id].approval >= quorum){
            transfers[id].sent = true;
            address payable to = transfers[id].to;
            uint amount = transfers[id].amount;
            to.transfer(amount);
        }

    }
    receive() external payable{}

    modifier onlyApprovers(){
        bool allowed =false;
        for(uint i=0;i<= approvers.length;i++){
            if(approvers[i] == msg.sender){
                allowed =true;
            }
    }
            require(allowed=true,'only approvers can approve');
            _;
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error when testing.

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Wallet.sol
> Artifacts written to /var/folders/kx/64r1zrfn28g8v6_sy50p98480000gn/T/test--50180-yxWHgIg50Wuu
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.6.0+commit.26b70077.Emscripten.clang


  Contract: Wallet
    ✔ should heve correct approvers and quorum (64ms)
    1) should create transfers
    > No events were emitted


  1 passing (6s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: Wallet
       should create transfers:
     Transaction: 0xd41ddeb4f3801cd59e065679a8a26180d92aa31778704e16ccfde77e01b9d830 exited with an error (status 0) after consuming all gas.
     Please check that the transaction:
     - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `assert` statements.
     - has enough gas to execute the full transaction.
     - does not trigger an invalid opcode by other means (ex: accessing an array out of bounds).
  StatusError: Transaction: 0xd41ddeb4f3801cd59e065679a8a26180d92aa31778704e16ccfde77e01b9d830 exited with an error (status 0) after consuming all gas.
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/Wallet.js:21:17)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I am new to solidity please help.I tried including gas and gasPrice directly to my transaction still the issue was not solved.